# Remove a Global Quick Action from Salesforce 1 App Home Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

I am viewing my home page in sf1 app. There I can see a global action Called New Contact. What I want to understand is is there any way to remove it from Home page? I want to add a custom quick action instead

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Global Publisher Layout To remove "New Contact" action from the Home Page by following these steps:

1. Enter Publisher Layout in the quick find box.
2. Select Publisher Layout under Global Actions.
3. Edit the Global Layout
4. In the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section, if you see a link to override the predefined actions, click the link to override.
5. Remove "New Contact" action by dragging it to the top.
6. Save your changes.

For more information: Refer to [Create Global Quick Actions in Salesforce Mobile App Customizations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/units/salesforce1_mobile_app_actions_global)

It will aslo help you in creating and adding custom quick actions in mobile app. You will get idea about how to create and remove actions from mobile app and from where to do this.